# How to completely disable Mysqli

Tags: mysql, php

It seems the new hacker tool refref has been launched, and apparently it abuses a bug in the mysqli extension. Now I do not use mysqli at all for my websites, so i thought the best way to fight off this refref tool was to completely disable mysqli.

[image]

These are the settings i have set in my php.ini. Is there a way I can disable mysqli completely with having to recompile PHP?

```
;extension=php_mysqli.dll

[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
;mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
```

Comment: check "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" on phpinfo, edit php.ini that you get from php.info, make sure commented ";extension=php_mysqli.dll". restart apache/iis

Comment: the path shows, /etc/php.ini, which is the file i used to get the values displayed above from.

Comment: may be there is separate configuration that load extension=mysqli.so. just try grep -R mysqli.so /etc/. usually the extension on /usr/lib/php/modules/mysqli.so or /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so.

Comment: The folder /usr/lib64/php/modules is there, but only contains phpcups.so, no other .so files.

Comment: weird. how about updatedb && locate mysqli.so ?.

Comment: finds nothing :(

Comment: seems your php not standard package from centos, seems you are compiled as static. either you recompile your php or try to disabled the php function from php ini using disable_functions (i never tried disable mysqli) http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: I tried it via disable_functions, added it in php.ini. restarted PHP. the values were loaded successfully, but mysqli remained active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a pre-compiled mysqli extension

you can still disable functions by adding this to your `php.ini`:

```
disable_functions = mysqli_affected_rows,mysqli_autocommit,mysqli_change_user,mysqli_character_set_name,mysqli_close,mysqli_commit,mysqli_connect,mysqli_connect_errno,mysqli_connect_error,mysqli_data_seek,mysqli_dump_debug_info,mysqli_debug,mysqli_errno,mysqli_error,mysqli_stmt_execute,mysqli_execute,mysqli_fetch_field,mysqli_fetch_fields,mysqli_fetch_field_direct,mysqli_fetch_lengths,mysqli_fetch_all,mysqli_fetch_array,mysqli_fetch_assoc,mysqli_fetch_object,mysqli_fetch_row,mysqli_field_count,mysqli_field_seek,mysqli_field_tell,mysqli_free_result,mysqli_get_cache_stats,mysqli_get_connection_stats,mysqli_get_client_stats,mysqli_get_charset,mysqli_get_client_info,mysqli_get_client_version,mysqli_get_host_info,mysqli_get_proto_info,mysqli_get_server_info,mysqli_get_server_version,mysqli_get_warnings,mysqli_init,mysqli_info,mysqli_insert_id,mysqli_kill,mysqli_more_results,mysqli_multi_query,mysqli_next_result,mysqli_num_fields,mysqli_num_rows,mysqli_options,mysqli_ping,mysqli_poll,mysqli_prepare,mysqli_report,mysqli_query,mysqli_real_connect,mysqli_real_escape_string,mysqli_real_query,mysqli_reap_async_query,mysqli_rollback,mysqli_select_db,mysqli_set_charset,mysqli_stmt_affected_rows,mysqli_stmt_attr_get,mysqli_stmt_attr_set,mysqli_stmt_bind_param,mysqli_stmt_bind_result,mysqli_stmt_close,mysqli_stmt_data_seek,mysqli_stmt_errno,mysqli_stmt_error,mysqli_stmt_fetch,mysqli_stmt_field_count,mysqli_stmt_free_result,mysqli_stmt_get_result,mysqli_stmt_get_warnings,mysqli_stmt_init,mysqli_stmt_insert_id,mysqli_stmt_more_results,mysqli_stmt_next_result,mysqli_stmt_num_rows,mysqli_stmt_param_count,mysqli_stmt_prepare,mysqli_stmt_reset,mysqli_stmt_result_metadata,mysqli_stmt_send_long_data,mysqli_stmt_store_result,mysqli_stmt_sqlstate,mysqli_sqlstate,mysqli_ssl_set,mysqli_stat,mysqli_store_result,mysqli_thread_id,mysqli_thread_safe,mysqli_use_result,mysqli_warning_count,mysqli_refresh,mysqli_bind_param,mysqli_bind_result,mysqli_client_encoding,mysqli_escape_string,mysqli_fetch,mysqli_param_count,mysqli_get_metadata,mysqli_send_long_data,mysqli_set_opt
```

Answer (score 1):

It is already deactivated. This is what the semicolon in front of the line

```
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

is for: It comments out the command to load this library.

Comment: Yeah i noticed in /etc/php.ini that its disabled already, but when I run <?php phpinfo(); ?> it is clearly enabled, as you can see from the screenshot. Also, var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect')); returns TRUE.

Comment: Is there any other ini file where this could be loaded? Also, is `/etc` the correct location for php.ini on Windows?

Comment: I am running CentOS 5.6, with php-fpm & nginx. Not Windows. /etc/php.ini is the correct php.ini file. I have editted it in the past, and changes always worked.

Comment: Is there some subdirectory for PHP configurations in /etc or elsewhere that might get referenced in `/etc/php.ini`? On Linux, the extension for the library should be `so`, not `dll`. Maybe try `grep -R mysqli.so /etc/*` to find any line referencing this library.

Comment: nothing found. mysqli.so cant be found on the entire system. I did: whereis mysqli.so. Also, i found my php extension dir: /opt/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626, and it only has memcache.so in it. No other files.